# Get file descriptor from `std::io::File::open`

Tags: c, posix, rust

I am writing binding for a C library, I'd like to call `std::io::File::open` as it's got error handling already. I then intend to pass the `fd` to C function.

I have looked at [std::io::fs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libstd/io/fs.rs.html), but the `fd` field is nothing like what I would have thought.

After some more digging I found [native::io::file::FileDesc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/src/native/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libnative/io/file_unix.rs.html), which indeed has `fn fd(&self) -> fd_t`, but doesn't seem like this is something I can access from an instance of `std::io::File`.

There appear to be [fs_from_raw_fd](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/rustuv/uvio/struct.UvIoFactory.html?search=raw_fd) method, it's the exact opposite to what I need.

Comment: I can think of one very dirty solution, basically shelling out to either `lsof` or `ls -la /proc/self/fd/` and looking for the file I have just opened with hope that it's only open once by this process. Not that I'm going to die without this... but would be great to know if this is really going to be a patch to standard library or there may be some trick?

Comment: It makes perfect sense that you can’t do it with a generic, runtime-agnostic `File` object. Suppose it’s using a runtime that isn’t based in C-style file descriptors?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan your point is absolutely valid. We should then consider removing `fs_from_raw_fd` method from `std::rt::rtio::IoFactory` trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get in the current version of Rust is via `native::io::file::open`.

```
use native::io::file::open;
use std::rt::rtio::{Open, Read};
let file = match open(&path.to_c_str(), Open, Read) {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(_) => return,
}
let fd = file.fd();
```

Comment: I thought there must be the way at somewhat lower level, but didn't realise this how it would be. Unfortunately it's not working for me with Rust nightly: https://gist.github.com/errordeveloper/5e2cbac2f9dbc33c3424

Comment: I submitted a [patch upstream](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/15643). Looks like it's the only way ;)

Comment: Ah, I forgot you can't unwrap on those Error types because it doesn't impl Show for some strange reason. I modified my example to use a match instead.

Comment: Looks like `rtio` ceased to be a thing years ago.

Answer (score 6):

```
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd; 

let path = Path::new("my.txt");
let display = path.display();

let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
    // The `description` method of `io::Error` returns a string that
    // describes the error
    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display,
                                               why.description()),
    Ok(file) => file,
};
println!("file descriptor: {}",file.as_raw_fd());
```